# Address of nodes keep overwriting each other when being added to linked list

Tags: c, memory, linked-list

I'm trying to use tasklist and pipe the output to my code and parse each line to then create nodes of every process. I will later be filtering through them but that is not in the code yet. I'm having problems with the `LIST`. I have implemented 3 `structs` for this program: `LIST` (head for first node, rear for last node and count for number of nodes in list), `NODE` (pointer to `PROCESS_INFO` and pointer to next `NODE`), `PROCESS_INFO` (4 char pointers for process name, PID, memory usage and cputime). I've used `printf` to track my code and everything seems to work properly until I get to adding them to the linked list. The address of each nodes are different but it always seems to overwrite the last one in the list instead of adding the new address of the node to the next* of the previous node.

I'm mostly positive my algorithm is correct, it's the same one I've used multiple times just with different data. My `malloc` functions have dynamic checks incase they fault and I've checked and played with my pointers incase I was missing a dereference of some sort but I get errors if I change anything so I don't think those are the problem funny enough.

The only thing I can think of that would be the problem is the fact that all this doing resides in a loop in a function (I read somewhere that pointers on a stack can't remember their address?). What would I have to change though to fix this? I've moved everything to main but nothing changed.

Struct Definitions:

```
typedef struct processInfo{
    char *pName;
    char *processId;
    char *memUsage;
    char *cpuTime;
}PROCESS_INFO;

typedef struct node{
    PROCESS_INFO* data;
    struct node* next;
}NODE;

typedef struct li{
    int num;
    NODE* head;
    NODE* rear;
}LIST;
```

Main function:

```
int main()
{
    LIST* list;
    list = buildList();
    printList(list);
}
```

List functions:

```
//function that creates a new list and returns it as null
LIST* createList()
{
    LIST* newListPtr;
    newListPtr = (LIST*)malloc(sizeof(LIST));

    if (newListPtr)
    {
        newListPtr->num = 0;
        newListPtr->head = NULL;
        newListPtr->rear = NULL;
    }
    return newListPtr;
}

//function that creates the struct for the information of the process
PROCESS_INFO* createPinfo(char* name, char* pid, char* kb, char* cTime)
{
    PROCESS_INFO* pInfoPtr;
    pInfoPtr = (PROCESS_INFO*)malloc(sizeof(PROCESS_INFO));

    if (pInfoPtr)
    {
        pInfoPtr->pName = name;
        pInfoPtr->processId = pid;
        pInfoPtr->memUsage = kb;
        pInfoPtr->cpuTime = cTime;
    }
    return pInfoPtr;
}

//function to create new node and set its data
NODE* createNode(PROCESS_INFO* dataPtr)
{
    NODE* nodePtr;
    nodePtr = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    if (nodePtr)
    {
        nodePtr->data = dataPtr;
        nodePtr->next = NULL;
    }
    return nodePtr;
}

//Get process information node via the path
PROCESS_INFO* parseInfoFromPath (char str[])
{
    char *pName;
    char *processId;
    char *memUsage;
    char *time;
    char *parse;

    parse = strtok(str, " ");
    pName = parse;

    parse = strtok(NULL, " ");
    processId = parse;

    parse = strtok(NULL, " "); //Console
    parse = strtok(NULL, " "); //session
    parse = strtok(NULL, " "); //memory
    memUsage = parse;

    parse = strtok(NULL, " ");
    parse = strtok(NULL, " ");
    parse = strtok(NULL, " ");
    parse = strtok(NULL, " "); //CPUTIME
    time = parse;

    PROCESS_INFO* pInfoPtr;
    pInfoPtr = createPinfo(pName, processId, memUsage, time); 

    return pInfoPtr;
}
```

BuildList() function where I seem to be getting the semantic error:

```
LIST* buildList()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char path[PATH_MAX];

    fp = popen("tasklist /v /fi \"STATUS eq running\" /nh ", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf( "CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError() );
        return;
    }

    LIST* list_;
    PROCESS_INFO* p;
    NODE* n;
    list_ = createList();

    while (fgets(path, PATH_MAX, fp) != NULL)
    {
        if (path != NULL)
       {
            //create the process info struct
            p = parseInfoFromPath(path);

            //create the node
            n = createNode(p);

            //add node to list
            //if empty list set as head
            if (list_->head == NULL){
                list_->head = n;
            }
            //otherwise set last->next to point to the new node
            else {
                list_->rear->next = n;
            }

            //rear points to last node
            list_->rear = n;
            (list_->num)++;

        }

    }
    //They always print out the same data!!!!
    printf("\nIn Loop: Head Node name: %s", list_->head->data->pName); 
    printf("\t\tIn Loop: Read Node name: %s", list_->rear->data->pName);
    return list_;
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not copying the strings for each input field you find. Instead you are holding pointers into your `path` buffer, which gets overwritten every time you do `fgets`. Try using `strdup` in `createPinfo`:

```
PROCESS_INFO* createPinfo(char* name, char* pid, char* kb, char* cTime)
{
    PROCESS_INFO* pInfoPtr;
    pInfoPtr = (PROCESS_INFO*)malloc(sizeof(PROCESS_INFO));

    if (pInfoPtr)
    {
        pInfoPtr->pName = strdup(name);
        pInfoPtr->processId = strdup(pid);
        pInfoPtr->memUsage = strdup(kb);
        pInfoPtr->cpuTime = strdup(cTime);
    }
    return pInfoPtr;
}
```

Also, since `strdup` allocates heap memory, don't forget to add a function to free the memory and call it every time you remove something from the list. Eg:

```
void destroyPinfo(PROCESS_INFO* pInfoPtr)
{
    if (pInfoPtr)
    {
        free(pInfoPtr->pName);
        pInfoPtr->pName = NULL;

        free(pInfoPtr->processId);
        pInfoPtr->processId = NULL;

        free(pInfoPtr->memUsage);
        pInfoPtr->memUsage = NULL;

        free(pInfoPtr->cpuTime);
        pInfoPtr->cpuTime = NULL;
    }
}
```

You will probably want to `NULL` check the results of `strdup` like you do `malloc` (I'm too lazy to add this in to the answer though, as long as you get the basic idea).